# $\int \frac{\cos(x)}{(1+\cos(x))^3} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, substitution

I'm having a bit of a trouble seeing how to factorize the result of substituting $t=\tan(x/2)$, $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2} \, dt$ into

$$\int \frac{\cos(x)}{(1+\cos(x))^3} \, dx$$

The result is

$$\int\frac{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{(1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})^3}\frac{2}{1+t^2} \, dt$$

that looks horrible.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focus on the rightmost factor. Multiply the numerator by it, and bring the $2$ outside the integral.

$$\int\frac{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{(1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})^3}\color{red}{\frac{2}{1+t^2}} \, dt = \color{red}{2}\int\frac{\frac{1-t^2}{\color{red}{(1+t^2)^2}}}{(1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})^3} \, dt$$

Focus on the denominator. For $1$ and $\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ make a common denonimator of $1+t^2$.

$$2\int\frac{\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}}{(\color{red}{1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}})^3} \, dt = 2\int\frac{\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}}{(\color{red}{\frac{2}{1+t^2}})^3} \, dt$$

Simplify the fraction.

$$2\int\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\frac{(1+t^2)^3}{8} \, dt = \frac14\int(1-t^2)(1+t^2) \, dt = \frac14\int(1-t^4) \, dt$$

To be explicit, in the above line we (1) cube the denominator, and (2) multiply the numerator of the fraction by the reciprocal of the denominator. (3) factor the $\frac18$ to the front, and (4) cancel like terms. Finally, for the final equality, (5) distribute like terms.

Answer (score 9):

Apply Integral Substitution: $\color{blue}{u=\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\quad \:dx=\frac{2}{1+u^2}du}$
$$\int \frac{\cos \left(x\right)}{\left(1+\cos \left(x\right)\right)^3}dx=\int \frac{1}{4}\left(1-u^4\right)du$$

Comment: How did you factor it that way?

Comment: do the least common where you can, and then simplifies

Comment: I don't see how the simplifying goes.

Comment: $-1$.  This is at best an overly complicated answer (not to mention the minus sign where a plus sign should be. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy minus sign??????

Comment: @Lasker : Yes.  Where the question had $1+\cos x$ you wrote $1-\cos x$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I had not noticed the error. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHardy The apparent sign error in the original version of this answer is due to the OP's changing the problem.  (See the comments after Olivier Oloa's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. By the change of variable that you have performed, one just gets
$$
\int \frac{\cos x}{(1+\cos x)^3}dx=\int\frac{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{(1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})^3}\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt=\int(1-t^4)\:dt
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you explain the "one just gets" bit?

Comment: Have seen the minus sign in the denominator?

Comment: Which explains that there's an error in my question.

Comment: @mavavilj You have $\left(1-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^3=\left(\frac{1+t^2}{1+t^2}-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^3=\left(\frac{2t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^3 $

Comment: @mavavilj Probably, yes.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{ \left(1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^3}\frac{2}{1+t^2}
$$

Start by multiplying the top and bottom of the expression above both by the common denominator $(1+t^2)^3$. The factor
$$
\frac{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{1+t^2}
$$
becomes
$$
(1-t^2)(1+t^2).
$$
The factor
$$
\left( 1+ \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \right)^3
$$
in the denominator becomes
$$
\Big( (1+t^2) + (1-t^2) \Big)
$$
and then simplifies to $2$.  You end up with
$$
\int \frac{(1-t^2)(1+t^2)} 2 \, dt = \int (1-t^4)\,dt.
$$

Comment: Wait. How is there a common denominator $(1+t^2)^3$? Can't see it.

Comment: Also Symbolab gives that the result should be $\frac{1}{4}\int (1-t^4)dt$

Comment: @mavavilj : The thing by which you need to multiply $1+ \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ to clear out the fractions is $1+t^2$.  Then $1$ becomes $1+t^2$ and the fraction $\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ becomes $1-t^2$.  So you can write $$ \begin{align} & \left( 1 + \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^3 (1+t^2)^3 \\  \\ = {} & \left( \left( 1+ \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \right) (1+t^2) \right)^3 \\  \\ = {} & \Big( (1+t^2) + (1-t^2) \Big) \end{align}$$and that becomes just $2$. $\qquad$